# Displaying checked and unchecked check box list after reading values from the database is not working

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, checkbox

Here is my PHP code:

```
  <?php 
include ('../connection.php');
  $query00 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ta_subjects WHERE USER_ID='$login_session' AND Subject_ID='00000001'",$connection);
    while ($row00 = mysql_fetch_array($query00))
              { 
                $thisSub[] = $row00['TopicName'];
              }
    $arrlength = count($thisSub);
    ?>
<!--=====Math=======-->
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="math" class="tab-pane fade in active"><br>
          <?php
            include '../connection.php';
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM topics WHERE SubjectID = '1'",$connection);
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
              { 
                $sub1 = $row['TopicName']; 
                ?>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                <?php
                $a=0;
                do
                {
                  if($thisSub[$a] == $sub1)
                  {
                    ?>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="sub" name="checklist1[]" value="<?php echo $sub1;?>" disabled checked>
                    <?php
                    $a = $a + 1;
                  }
                  else
                    $a = $a + 1;
                }while($arrlength == $a);
                ?>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="sub" name="checklist1[]" value="<?php echo $sub1;?>" disabled>
                    <label><?php echo $sub1;?></label>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
          ?>
        </div>
```

[It should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNScb.png)

I am comparing the list of all subjects from the database and the subjects with the same ID from the database also and mark it as checked.
But it only displays the first checked check box and ends the loop. So the only checked check box is only Algebra. What am I missing here?

---

#### Solved

Solved it by putting the second check box in the else block instead of under the while loop as what @dreamster suggested.

Comment: That do-while condition doesn't look right, and where is `$arrlength` defined? Where is `$thisSub` defined? etc etc.

Comment: That "SELECT * " doesn't look right either

Comment: I edited my post. This is bugging me for almost 3 hours now. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM topics WHERE SubjectID = '1'", $connection);
```

should be

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM topics", $connection);
```

also change

```
if($thisSub[$a] == $sub1)
```

to

```
if(in_array($sub1, $thisSub))
```

Comment: the SubjectID should be there so that it would only get the topics equal to that SubjectID. It is for the category of the topic.

Comment: @rodortega oh, I see. so are you sure there are enough subjects with SubjectID as 1?

Comment: @rodortega try changing the if statement as I mentioned.

Comment: Still doesn't work. It says "in_array() expects paramater 2 to be array, null given in.."

Comment: which means there are no rows that satisfies the condition: `USER_ID='$login_session'`. You could avoid the error by declaring `$thisSub = array()`

Comment: I avoided the error, but the checking of check box didn't work

Comment: make sure $login_session has some id in it and make sure the user have some records in the db. the code is fine now. Also, I think the code for second checkbox should be inside else block.

Comment: It's okay now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @rodortega happy to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

am not sure if i got you right but try something like this, we can help you better if you gave us where some variables came from and why is the do while for?

```
$a = 0;
// $thisSub = []; put this before you first while loop 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
      { 
        $sub1 = $row['TopicName']; ?>
        <div class="col-sm-6">

    <input type="checkbox" class="sub" name="checklist1[]" value="<?php echo $sub1;?>" disabled <?php echo (in_array($sub1, $thisSub)) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> >
    <?php $a++; ?>

            <label><?php echo $sub1;?></label>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
```

Comment: you are comparing an array with a string $thisSub[$a] == $sub1, you can't just do this, you have to use in_array

Comment: I already did that as requested by dreamster. Still giving me errors  "in_array() expects paramater 2 to be array, null given in.."

Comment: make sure you have items in $thisSub array, and follow the instructions from dreamster, also define your array before the first while  $thisSub = [];

Comment: I avoided the error, but the checking of check box didn't work